# IE9 rendering of XML/XSLT fails with error XSLT8690

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

I have a webpage that is served as XML/XSL file pair. With IE9 - Version 9.0.8112.16421. Update Versions: 9.0.10 (KB2744842) the rendering fails on Windows 2008 R2

[image]

In the script console I see the following message:

```
XSLT8690: The download of the specified resource has failed
```

But in the web server logs I see the XSLT file being downloaded.

Enabling Compatibility View seems to solve the rendering problem.

Same browser version on Windows 7 (64-bit) renders without problems even if compatibility view is off.

With HTTP it works fine, only failing with HTTPS.

Because of this I tried other things: import the certificate, import the CA root certificate, add a HTTP header X-UA-Compatible with IE=IE7, IE=EmulateIE7.

Using IE Developer Tools (aka F12) I captured the network. This is the export for the failing system:

```
URL Method  Result  Type    Received    Taken   Initiator   Wait??  Start?? Request??   Response??  Cache read??    Gap??
https://antares/cgi_bin/SystemInfo/start    GET 200 text/xml    7.29 KB 94 ms   refresh 0   16  46  32  0   20
/cgi_bin/SystemInfo/systeminfo.xsl      (Aborted)   text/xsl    65 B    16 ms   (Pending...)    62  16  0   0   0   36
/cgi_bin/SystemInfo/systeminfo.xsl      (Aborted)   text/xsl    65 B    < 1 ms  (Pending...)    78  0   0   0   0   36
```

And the working one:

```
URL Method  Result  Type    Received    Taken   Initiator   Wait??  Start?? Request??   Response??  Cache read??    Gap??
https://antares/cgi_bin/SystemInfo/start    GET 200 text/xml    7,29 KB 78 ms   click   0   0   0   31  0   107
/cgi_bin/SystemInfo/systeminfo.xsl  GET 200 text/xsl    6,84 KB 16 ms       62  0   0   16  0   107
/cgi_bin/SystemInfo/style.css   GET 200 text/css    1,50 KB 15 ms   <link rel="stylesheet" />   78  0   15  0   0   92
/cgi_bin/SystemInfo/color.css   GET 200 text/css    0,66 KB 15 ms   <link rel="stylesheet" />   78  15  0   0   0   92
```

Comment: Does the XML or XSLT have a `DOCTYPE` node which might reference additional resources?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: no, they don't.